# Duda con HashSet

Tags: java

¿Cómo podría usar el siguiente código con un HashSet?.

Esta parte del código se usa para asignar un Directivo a un trabajador, pero tengo un problema en la parte que marco con negrita ya que como yo lo hago me marca error.

El Hashset que estoy utilizando es : `private HashSet<Empleado> empleados;`

Método original con array :

```
for (int i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
     if (empleados[i] instanceof Directivo && empleados[i].getDNI().equals(DNI_directivo)) {
            **d = (Directivo) empleados[i];**
      }
}

 e = new TrabajadorObra(d, DNI, nombre, cargo, nomina);
```

Lo intento hacer de esta forma para Hashset pero me da error.

```
for (Empleado e : empleados) {

     if (e instanceof Directivo && e.getDni().equals(dni4)){

           d = (Directivo) empleados;
      }

  e = new TrabajadorObra(d, DNI, nombre, cargo, nomina);
```

Comment: Si `empleados` en de tipo `HashSet` por qué lo tratas como un arreglo y no dices que te da error: `empleados.length`, `empleados[i]`??

Comment: Perdón si me he expresado mal, el primer código es con un array simple y el segundo es el intento de hacerlo con un HashSet, quiero poder hacerlo con hashset no con un array simple.

Comment: Esto es incorrecto `(Directivo) empleados`, intentas castear un `HashSet` a `Directivo`, debes tener error ahí

Comment: @InThaHouse es importante que cuando preguntes agregues el error que obtienes, esto para tener más detalles sobre el problema. El problema es como indica E.Betanzos este casting : (Directivo) empleados ¿Que es Directivo?

Comment: Directivo es una clase.

Comment: Pues claro que es una clase, pero `Directivo` es un `Empleado`? Creo que @E. Betanzos ya pillo tu error. Estas casteando el hashset y no el empleado